# Opening a file and writing to Text box c++

Tags: c++, winapi

Okay, so I need this button that, when clicked, opens a user-specified file.  After the file is opened, it needs to be read/copied into the text box below that button.  Eventually other things need to happen but I'm having trouble just doing that.  The following is the code I have so far for creating the GUI, then I'm completely lost on how to proceed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
char szClassName[ ] = "WindowsApp";

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpszArgument,
                    int nFunsterStil)

{
    HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
    MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */

    /* The Window structure */
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

    /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
    /* Use Windows's default color as the background of the window */
    wincl.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);

    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;

    /* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
           0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
           szClassName,         /* Classname */
           "Software Engineering II",       /* Title Text */
           WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, /* default window */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
           900,                 /* The programs width */
           500,                 /* and height in pixels */
           HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
           NULL,                /* No menu */
           hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
           NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
           );

    /* Make the window visible on the screen */
    ShowWindow (hwnd, nFunsterStil);

    /* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    /* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
    return messages.wParam;
}


#define ID_LABEL 
static HWND hwndLbl1;
static HWND hwndLbl2;
static HWND hwndLbl3;
static HWND hwndLbl4;
bool buttonPressed = false;

/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
             hwndLbl1 = CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"),TEXT("Building File Selection"),
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
             10,10,150,25,
             hwnd, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL
             );
             hwndLbl2 = CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"),TEXT("Class File Selection"),
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
             500,10,150,25,
             hwnd, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL
             );
             hwndLbl3 = CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"),TEXT("Building No."),
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
             10, 75, 150, 25,
             hwnd, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL
             );
             hwndLbl4 = CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"),TEXT("Room No."),
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
             500,75,150,25,
             hwnd, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL
             );
             // Building Room open
             CreateWindow(TEXT("button"),TEXT("Open"),
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 
             10,40,80,25,
             hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL
             );
             // Classroom open
             CreateWindow(TEXT("button"),TEXT("Open"),
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
             500, 40, 80, 25,
             hwnd, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL
             ); 
             CreateWindow(TEXT("button"),TEXT("Search"),
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
             800,100,80,25,
             hwnd, (HMENU) 3, NULL, NULL
             );
             // The information should be read from here.
             CreateWindow(TEXT("edit"), TEXT("Text goes here"),
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
             10, 100, 300, 20, 
             hwnd, (HMENU) 5, NULL, NULL
             );
             CreateWindow(TEXT("edit"),TEXT("Text goes here"),
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
             500,100,300,20,
             hwnd, (HMENU) 5, NULL, NULL
             );
             CreateWindow(TEXT("edit"),TEXT("Output from Building"),
             WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_READONLY | WS_BORDER,
             10, 150, 400, 250,
             hwnd, (HMENU) 6, NULL, NULL
             );
             CreateWindow(TEXT("edit"),TEXT("Output from Room file"),
             WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_READONLY | WS_BORDER,
             500, 150, 380, 250,
             hwnd, (HMENU) 7, NULL, NULL
             );
             CreateWindow(TEXT("button"),TEXT("Continue"),
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 
             500,410,80,25,
             hwnd, (HMENU) 8, NULL, NULL
             );
             CreateWindow(TEXT("button"),TEXT("Show .PRN"),
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 
             600,410,80,25,
             hwnd, (HMENU) 9, NULL, NULL
             );
             CreateWindow(TEXT("button"),TEXT("Show .LOG"),
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 
             700,410,80,25,
             hwnd, (HMENU) 10, NULL, NULL
             ); 
             CreateWindow(TEXT("button"),TEXT("Show .CSV"),
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 
             800,410,80,25,
             hwnd, (HMENU) 11, NULL, NULL
             );
             break;
             // This is where you issue commands for buttons
             // To read from files and output them into those 2 text boxes that are ID'd (HMENU) 6 and (HMENU 7.
        case WM_COMMAND:
             if(LOWORD(wParam) == 1){
                  FILE * BuildingFile;
                  buttonPressed = true;
                /*  ifstream infile;
                  infile.open ("Bldgs-Rms-Txt-File-2012-08082012.txt");
                  if(infile.is_open()){
                                       while(infile.good())
                                                           print to buildingtextbox (char) infile.get(); 
                  //BuildingFile = fopen("Bldgs-Rms-Txt-File-2012-08082012.txt","r");     // In the argument of MessageBox, this is the PARENT WINDOW, which should be the same for all
                  */
                  }
             if (LOWORD (wParam) == 2){
                   FILE * RoomFile;
                   RoomFile = fopen("cbm_005_003639_201310_08082012.DAT","r");
                  }
             if (LOWORD (wParam) == 6){
                       std::cout << "chuck";
                        }               
             break;        
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps reducing the code from 200+ lines to something reasonable for this forum might get you an answer. It is far too long.

Comment: I thought of that, however I wasn't sure you'd be able to understand the whole GUI that was referencing in the problem

Comment: Use a debugger to narrow the problem down. Anybody would need to do this to answer this question

Comment: There's no error, I just literally don't know how to do the next step

Comment: Program terminates/Program crashes/It goes away and makes coffee/Predicts the second coming of Christ  - what is meant by "Eventually other things need to happen"

Comment: There is nothing even *resembling* a question in this post.

Comment: After the file is opened, it needs to be read/copied into the text box below that button. Eventually other things need to happen but I'm having trouble just doing that. 

The obvious question

Comment: @Drew Dormann Notice how someone saw not only one, but two questions in my original post.  I suggest reading before you start nitpicking because the pasted code is "too long for you to read." I clearly stated my intent for the code, what I am having trouble with, and what I've done so far.

Comment: @RELENTLESS00G I think you're quoting someone else.  Good luck!

Comment: @Drew Dormann Thank you, but I was focusing on how you see no question in the post, not Ed Heal 's nonsense

Comment: @RELENTLESS00G That is correct.  You will get better results if you remember to ask a question.  I hope that advice proves helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to preserve the window handles (hWnd)s from the CreateWindow calls.

```
// Up top
#include <string>

// Class member:
HWND building1text;

// Saving the hWnd on the CreateWindow call
building1text = CreateWindow(TEXT("edit"),TEXT("Output from Building"),
             WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_READONLY | WS_BORDER,
             10, 150, 400, 250,
             hwnd, (HMENU) 6, NULL, NULL
             );
```

2) Then you can use SetWindowText(hWnd, LPCTSTR) to put the text into the text box.

```
string lineString, totalString;
// open file here
while(infile.good()) {
    // concatenate next line from file (works if file contains 
    // null-terminated lines of stuff
    getline(infile, lineString, '\n');
    totalString += lineString;
}
SetWindowText(building1text, totalString);
```

I don't have a compiler set up, but hopefully that works for you.  Of course, I don't know how your data file is formatted, either.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, I saw the setedittext and couldn't figure out it, I guess the SetWindowText works easier.  Also where did you get building1text as the hwnd from? I assume you just made it up for that specific window.

May I ask was the question so hard to find or are the others just being idiotic?

Comment: building1text is declared in the sample code at top.  Your program is not keeping the HWNDs from any CreateWindow calls, but you will need them to access those controls.  In response to your second question... I think you will need to learn how to work with strings and read your files into them.  I hope this is enough in pointers for you to continue along that journey from here.

Comment: Whoops.  There is no class.  Well, you could declare your HWNDs at file scope.

Comment: You don't need to remember `HWND`s to access controls. You'd usually call [GetDlgItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481.aspx) to reference controls by ID. As you pointed out, the second parameter to `SetWindowText` is of type `LPCTSTR`, so you cannot use a `std::string`. Either use `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` or call `SetWindowTextW` and go with `std::wstring`.

Comment: Thank you, IInspectable.  Wouldn't the GetDlgItem and subsequent call be twice as much as using the preserved HWND?

Comment: @MarkMeyers Okay, while I understand what's going on, I'm not too sure where I put the  second part (#2) at in the code? (Sorry, I feel like an idiot lol)

Comment: @IInspectable I tried putting what mark and you said into what happens when the button is clicked, but for some reason it's telling me "good" isn't declared

Comment: I have gotten now to feel fairly confident that you don't know how to read and write C++.  For however painful this may seem, I think it will be necessary for you to go through the motions of learning the C++ lexicon and syntax, like with a C++ tutorial, maybe for a few weeks, to get to the point of understanding how to write the statements and interpret the compiler errors.